# Proof of Cayley-Hamilton theorem over any field $\Bbb K$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-polynomial, cayley-hamilton

I'm currently studying the Cayley-Hamilton theorem for an exam, and I do not quite get the proof presented in the lecture. It was structured as follows: first we'll prove it over $\mathbb{C}$ using the fact that every matrix is trigonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ and then generalize to an arbitrary field $\mathbb{K}$. The first part of the proof is very comprehensive, what I don't get is the final generalization:

We know that $\forall A \in \text{M}_{n\text{x}n}(\mathbb{K}): \text{det}(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\cdot A(1,\sigma 1) \cdot ... \cdot A(n, \sigma n)$

$\Longrightarrow \text{char}_{A}(x) = \text{det}(A-xI_n)\in \mathbb{K}[x, A(1,1), A(1,2), ..., A(n,n)]$

But from the formula from the determinant we get that the coefficients are in $\mathbb{R}$, in fact in {-1,1}  $\Longrightarrow \text{char}_{A}(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x, A(1,1), A(1,2), ..., A(n,n)]$

Consider now the matrix $\text{char}_{A}(A)$ and write it as:
$\text{char}_{A}(A) = (q_{i,j}(A(1,1), ..., A(n,n)))_{i,j}$   with $q_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}[A(1,1), ..., A(n,n)]$

Now since we have proved the thm over $\mathbb{C}$ it works over $\mathbb{R}$ in particular. Hence, $q_{i,j}(A(1,1), ..., A(n,n)) = 0,  \ \forall (A(1,1), ..., A(n,n)) \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$

We deduce $q_{i,j}$ is the zero polynomial, and this is independent of the field we want to prove Cayley-Hamilton on.
$\blacksquare$

I'm not quite sure why it follows that the theorem holds on $\mathbb{R}$? To prove it over $\mathbb{C}$ we explicitly use the property that every matrix is trigonalizable. Now we view the characteristic polynomial as a formal expression with $n^2$ variables which as a $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ fucntion is the zero function then also as a $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ function. And this concludes the proof? I find the final steps a bit shady, I really don't understand how we can simply generalize to every field...

Comment: By “trigonalizable”, do you mean “triangularisable/triangulable” (to make a matrix triangular) or “tridiagonalisable” (to make a matrix tridiagonal)?

Comment: slightly different: observe that coefficients live in $\mathbb Z$ so you may consider each polynomial $q_{i,j} \in \mathbb Z[\mathbf x]$ and each evaluates to $0$ under *every* evaluation map (substitution homomorphism) into $\mathbb C$, since Cayley Hamilton holds everywhere in $\mathbb C$, hence must be the zero polynomial. Now use a suitable homormorphism $\phi: \mathbb Z[\mathbf x]\longrightarrow \mathbb K$ and of course a zero polynomial is still zero under this homormophism. One name for this is *principle of permanence of identities*; it's really a property for commutative rings.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. What would a homomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ look like?

Comment: For avoidance of doubt, the homomorphism is not $\phi: \mathbb Z\longrightarrow \mathbb K$.  If you like, you can write this as a composition $ \mathbb Z[\mathbf x]\longrightarrow\mathbb K[\mathbf x]\longrightarrow \mathbb K$ where the first acts as the identity/inclusion (if characteristic zero) or acts modulo $p$ if positive characteristic $p$ and the second one sends $x_i$ (or $x_{i,j}$ depending on labeling) into elements in your field.  The *principle* I outlined is nicely walked through in the early sections of the Modules chapter in Artin's *Algebra*.

Answer (score 1):

A few things here; I don't know if you are familiar with field extension, if you are not just consider (this is not the real definition) that a field extension $\mathbb{L}$ of $\mathbb{K}$ is a field which verifies $\mathbb{L} \supset \mathbb{K}$, just as $\mathbb{C} \supset \mathbb{R}$.

Given a field extension we can always transform a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space $V$ into a $\mathbb{L}$-vector space $V_\mathbb{L}$ by setting:
$$V_\mathbb{L} = \mathbb{L} \otimes_\mathbb{K} V$$
This tensor product is "functorial", which means each linear morphism can be extended to $V_\mathbb{L}$.
We also get a similar operation with the dual space:
$$V_\mathbb{L}^* =\hom_\mathbb{K}(V,\mathbb{L})$$

But this is not very important if you don't get it: you can always get back to a matrix representation with the injections:
$$V \simeq \mathbb{K}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{L}^n \simeq V_\mathbb{L} $$
$$\hom_\mathbb{K} (V,V) \simeq \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{K}) \longrightarrow \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{L}) \simeq \hom_\mathbb{L} (V_\mathbb{L},V_\mathbb{L}) $$
Things are easier.

It seems you already know this result: if an endomorphism $u$ of $V$ is extended to $u_{\mathbb{L}}$, endomorphism of $V_\mathbb{L}$,
$$\chi^\mathbb{K}_u = \chi^\mathbb{L}_{u_\mathbb{L}} \in \mathbb{K}[x]$$
Which can also be stated as: the characteristic polynomial does not depend on the field extension. This is the same things that you've done with your matrices.

So let's get back to our theorem of Cayley-Hamilton: I will generalize it for any field. I think it is already clear for you that if $u$, or if you prefer $A$ your matrix, is trigonalizable the theorem is basically free and obvious. So what we do here is for any $u$, $\chi_u$ is not necessarily split. So we need to choose a field extension $\mathbb{L}$ in which it is (since the polynomial does not depend on the choice of extension).

What we do with $\mathbb{R}$ is to choose $\mathbb{C}$ but in general we can define the *splitting field* of a polynomial $P$, we just take its decomposition :
$$P = P_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots P_r^{\alpha_r} $$
and take
$$Q = P_1 \cdots P_r$$
If your field is perfect, we can easily define it with $P$ and $P\wedge P'$ but I'll let you do it.

Then we take $\mathbb{L} = \mathbb{K}[x] / (Q)$, you can easily see that $\mathbb{L}$ is a field on which $P$ is split. If you don't get this part, stick to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

Once you have your field $\mathbb{L}$, you know that $u_\mathbb{L}$ or $A_{\mathbb{L}}$ (the same endomorphism/matrix but in your extended space) is trigonalizable since $\chi^\mathbb{L}_u = \chi^\mathbb{K}_u$ is split in $\mathbb{L}$ (your ambiant field). Hence $u_\mathbb{L}$ (or $A_\mathbb{L}$) is trigonalizable, thus:
$$\chi^\mathbb{K}_u (u_\mathbb{L}) = \chi^\mathbb{L}_u (u_\mathbb{L}) =0$$
But $v \mapsto v_\mathbb{L}$ is an injective algebra morphism, hence
$$0 = \chi_u (u_\mathbb{L}) = (\chi_u (u))_\mathbb{L}$$
thus $\chi_u (u)=0$.
Here you go!